# Different groups of checkbox not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I prefer to get checked checkboxes from a specific checkbox group, depending on which button I have clicked, I used `$('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:checked')`. This will ensure that the checked checkboxes from only the coffee or animals checkbox group are selected. But it's not working as I expected.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Lion" name="animals" checked />Lion<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Tiger" name="animals" />Tiger<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Elephant" name="animals" />Elephant<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Girafee" name="animals" />Girafee<br>
        <input type="submit" id="__mainAnimals" />
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Coffe" name="drinks" checked />Coffe<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Tea" name="drinks" />Tea<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Milk" name="drinks" />Milk<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Mocha" name="drinks" />Mocha<br>
        <input type="submit" id="__mainDrinks" />
    </div>
    <div id="__DIVresult"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#__mainAnimals').click(function () {
            getSelectedCheckBoxes('animals');
        });

        $('#__mainDrinks').click(function () {
            getSelectedCheckBoxes('drinks');
        });

        var getSelectedCheckBoxes = function (groupName) {
            var result = $('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:checked');
            if (result.length > 0) {
                var resultString = result.length + " checkboxe(s) checked<br/>";
                result.each(function () {
                    resultString += $(this).val() + "<br/>";
                });
                $('__DIVresult').html(resultString);
            }
            else {
                $('__DIVresult').html("No checkbox checked");
            }
        };
    });

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @arrafat, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1st id selector is `#` so `$('__DIVresult')` should be `$('#__DIVresult')`

2nd An ID should start with a letter for compatibility

> Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, **an ID should start with a letter for compatibility**.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

3rd some small update, added two result div, one for animal one for drink:

```
<hr>
animals Result:
<div id="DIVresultanimals"></div>
<hr>
drinks Result:
<div id="DIVresultdrinks"></div>
```

Then target them dynamically with `$('#DIVresult'+groupName).html(resultString);`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Lion" name="animals" checked />Lion
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Tiger" name="animals" />Tiger
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Elephant" name="animals" />Elephant
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Girafee" name="animals" />Girafee
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="mainAnimals" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Coffe" name="drinks" checked />Coffe
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Tea" name="drinks" />Tea
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Milk" name="drinks" />Milk
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Mocha" name="drinks" />Mocha
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="mainDrinks" />
</div>
<hr>
animals Result:
<div id="DIVresultanimals"></div>
<hr>
drinks Result:
<div id="DIVresultdrinks"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainAnimals').click(function() {
      getSelectedCheckBoxes('animals');
    });

    $('#mainDrinks').click(function() {
      getSelectedCheckBoxes('drinks');
    });

    var getSelectedCheckBoxes = function(groupName) {
      var result = $('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:checked');
      if (result.length > 0) {
        var resultString = result.length + " checkboxe(s) checked<br/>";
        result.each(function() {
          resultString += $(this).val() + "<br/>";
        });
        $('#DIVresult'+groupName).html(resultString);
      } else {
        $('#DIVresult'+groupName).html("No checkbox checked");
      }
    };
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your drink and animal section you are not separating the two so when you use your click function it doesn't discriminate between the tow sections. Once you add each one to a class then the button will only call the checked items that are actually checked.

```
<html>
```

```
   <form>
    <input name="selector[]" id="ani" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Lion"  />Lion</br>
        <input name="selector[]" id="ani" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Tiger" />Tiger</br>
        <input name="selector[]" id="ani" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Elephant" />Elephant</br>
        <input name="selector[]" id="ani" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Girafee" />Girafee</br>

    <input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" /></br>
      <textarea id="t"></textarea>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>


     function updateTextArea() {         
 var allVals = [];
 $('.ads_Checkbox:checked').each(function() {
   allVals.push($(this).val());
 });
 $('#t').val(allVals);
```

}

```
    $('#save_value').click(function(){
        $('.ads_Checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                updateTextArea();
        });
    });
```

Inside this code I have named each animal and placed them in a class so I could recall them from an array. I hoped this helped.